# Sticky Header Overlaps Mobile Navigation

Tags: jquery, mobile, sass

I have racked my brain for a few days now trying to fix this. I have a sticky header that uses a little jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
        $('header').addClass("sticky");
       }
       else{
         $('header').removeClass("sticky");
       }
    });
</script>
```

Then, within my header I have the mobile menu that is hidden using a media query until a min-width of 750px. The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="menu-button">
    <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i>
    <span>Menu</span>
</div>

<div class="secondary-nav-wrapper">
    <nav role="navigation" class="responsive-nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="menu-title">
                Where to?
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php" class="home" title="Home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contact/contact.php" class="contact" title="About and Contact">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="portfolio.php" class="portfolio" title="Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

I have been using SASS for my CSS, which looks like this:

```
    body.shift-left {
    background-color: $softblack;

    div.page {
        @include transition(all 0.25s ease 0s);
    left: -345px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;

        header {
            div.secondary-nav-wrapper {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        right: 12px;
        top: 8px;
        width: 324px;

                nav.responsive-nav {
                    display: block;

                    ul {
                        padding: 0;
                        margin: 0;
                        line-height: 46px;

                        li.menu-title {
                            font-family: $font-primary;
                            color: white;
                            font-size: 2em;
              background-color: $blackgrey;
              padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
                        }
                        li {
                            font-family: $font-default;
                            color: $lightgrey;
                            font-size: 1.5em;

                            a {
                                display: block;
                            }
                        }
                        hr {
                             border: 0;
                             height: 1px; 
                             background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
                             background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
                             background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
                             background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, (finally) getting to the point. It works perfectly on a desktop, exactly the way I want it to look:

[Desktop version looks fine](http://kevindenchdesign.com/multimedia/screenshots/Stack-overflow-issue.PNG)

Then whenever I get on a mobile device: [As you can see,](http://kevindenchdesign.com/multimedia/screenshots/IMG_0263.jpg) the header overlaps the menu, looking terrible.

How the menu works: I am using jQuery to add a class to body, and when it does, I have styled it so that body moves either right or left depending on the menu.

The HTML where the class is added looks like this.

```
<body class="" id="home">
    <div class="page">

      <header>
```

I have no idea what is going on. I have looked up if a fixed position breaks on mobile, but received no clear answer; I have tried using z-index and that doesn't matter. I even tried positioning it absolutely, and everything but the background color on "div.page" goes to the front. That "fix" looked okay for a minute, until I scrolled down and the header broke and the logo went on the top position.

If you would like to see for yourself what I am talking about, my test site is: **kevindenchdesign.com/playground/index.php** Stay on the index page, as I am trying to fix the problem for mobile on that page first. The other pages are broken and a lot of links aren't working too well. So go ahead and inspect the index page.

I really appreciate any help or advice on this one, since having a navigation working properly for mobile is a good thing. I am open to other ways of doing the menu too if you can't figure it out and are willing to share code.

Thanks again, have a great weekend.

Comment: I deleted my comment about the suggestion, feel free to follow - then I can delete this to close the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix would be to add a padding top to the  of the class secondary-nav-wrapper like this

EDIT: Use it only @media() you are using so at the desktop view it does not have any problems

```
@media (max-width: 750px) {      // Your breakpoint
    .secondary-nav-wrapper ul{
       padding-top: 80px;        //This would be the height of you sticky navbar
    }
}
```

So that the sticky navbar does not overlap the secondary navigation on the right hand side!

What will happen is that when the browser windows is more than 750px the above style will not be applied and when it drops below that the padding-top will kick in to make the menu visible all the time !

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider that as an alternative option. In my head I like the idea of the menu looking like it drops down from either side.

My only quarrel with that is: how do I rectify the functionality differences between the desktop and mobile versions?

Comment: I did not totatly understand your concern this time. I updated my answer to further explain how you can only make the quick fix for mobiles that are narrower than 750px. Not all mobile browsers have the same standards for html and css so you have to be carefull and test with different devices!

Comment: The only way it's not a perfect solution is because on a mobile device the body will slide left, while the header stays stationary. Simply adding margin or padding makes the solution look slightly patchwork, because everything but the header is moving. If I had enough reputation points, I would vote it up, but I don't think it completely solves my problem. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Well you could use snap.js move all the body all the way to the right or to the left! It needs some more coding and a little javascript but it works perfeclty! http://jakiestfu.github.io/Snap.js/

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that it was the `position: fixed` that was causing the problem and since I couldn't find a viable sticky header solution without `position: fixed` then I just positioned the header itself:

```
body.shift-right {
    div.page {
        header {
            position:fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 345px;
        }
    }
}
```

And so forth. I'll give you credit Alen because your solution inspired me to explore alternatives. It'd be really nice if I could find a solution that degraded nicely, but maybe not. This is a little extra work, but I guess it's fine.

Comment: Be sure to check the behaviour of the position: fixed; in Windows Phone , Android and iOS browsers. It does not allways behave as it should. Don't bother with any version of Opera mini!